# How to set the JDK for Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, openjdk, jdk

I can't compile a *default* new project for Android 2.1 [because](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7535471/1505348)(?) the JDK used by Android Studio is JDK 1.7 but it should be JDK 1.6.

To change it I go to *File* -> *Project Structure* and try to find the JDK 1.6 location.

But when I select its directory and press <kbd>OK</kbd> I get the following error:

> Please choose a valid JDK directory

[image: Please choose a valid JDK directory]

As you can see on the screenshoot I'm trying to set Java 6 OpenJDK 64-bits as the new JDK.

What can I do? Isn't Android Studio compatible with OpenJDK and should I use Oracle JDK instead?

Comment: Have you tried the `bin` folder?

Comment: I tried with: `./bin` | `./jre` | `./jre/bin` same message for all

Comment: For me I just had to use the folder above `/jre` in the directory structure, so my path is `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle` and not `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre`. I assumed the path should end in `/jre` since the default path (the "embedded" JDK) does, but it turns out if you go look in the default folder, it's a folder called "jre" which *contains another folder called "jre"*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that Android Studio does not recognize OpenJDK, so I need to [install the OracleJDK](https://askubuntu.com/a/55960/62483).

Then I choose the path to Oracle JDK and it worked!

Comment: i installed it but im unable to set its path variable. can you please tell me how can i do that?

Comment: Yes, first make sure that `java -version` output correctly your [Java version](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10557023/). Then, on the AS window choose `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0/`. That was enough for me at that moment :-)

Comment: This should be done only after good consideration: this has massive legal implications, since Oracle changed their licensing terms in quite surprising ways. Typically you do not want to use Oracle java any longer in a comercial environment.

Answer (score 26):

I'm using OpenJDK 7 with Android Studio and it works just fine. (I don't even have Oracle JDK installed at the moment.)

On that screen that you are showing (Project Structure-->SKD Location) I have the following path for the *JDK location*: `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64`.

Answer (score 10):

By inspecting `studio.sh`, you can also set one of `STUDIO_JDK`, `JDK_HOME` or `JAVA_HOME` environment variables to point to the JDK location.

---

`studio.sh` checks the `STUDIO_JDK`, `JDK_HOME`, and `JAVA_HOME` environment variables in order:

```
if [ -n "$STUDIO_JDK" -a -x "$STUDIO_JDK/bin/java" ]; then
  JDK="$STUDIO_JDK"
elif [ -n "$JDK_HOME" -a -x "$JDK_HOME/bin/java" ]; then
  JDK="$JDK_HOME"
elif [ -n "$JAVA_HOME" -a -x "$JAVA_HOME/bin/java" ]; then
  JDK="$JAVA_HOME"
```

So you can just set them as appropriate and then Studio will pick it up.

Comment: This works for windows too. useful if you have a JDK with DCEVM as default in JAVA_HOME which does not work with android studio.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

1. Find out the java directory:

   ```
   $ echo $JAVA_HOME
   /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
   ```
2. Open Android Studio and then File-> Project Structure.
3. Under *SDK Location* I past the java directory from above
4. Wait a couple of seconds and I got "0 errores 0 advertencias"

It worked! :)

Answer (score 2):

Steps I followed:

1. Opened terminal and enter `echo $JAVA_HOME`
2. Copied the path displayed in terminal - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> copy in Ubuntu terminal
3. In Android studio - Project Structure - Pasted the copied path
4. Waited for the software to recognize and update the settings
5. This solved the problem of Invalid Jdk settings

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this problem. 
I use AS 2.1 and JDK1.7 while it required me to update JDK1.8 for some functions. I download the java setup file. Maybe I only installed jre but not jdk. so AS always warn me that "Please choose a valid JDK directory".
So I guess the asker's problem same as me that you should install a JDK but not jre.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `./bin` folder with a JDK and Android Studio, you can set the `STUDIO_JDK` variable before running `studio.sh` in a terminal:

```
STUDIO_JDK=./bin/jdk/ ./bin/android-studio/bin/studio.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you might have installed the jdk somewhere else for e.g. `/usr/local/java`. In my case also I saw the same folder name in the directory shown in your screenshot.

So just check if the jdk is present somewhere else.