# Changing JDK from Open JDK to Oracle JDK

Tags: jdk, openjdk, android-studio, android-sdk

I installed Android Studio in Ubuntu by following two commands:

1. `sudo apt-get ubuntu-make`
2. `umake android`

It installed with OpenJDK bydefault using Ubuntu Developer Tool.

Now I want to change JDK from Open JDK to Oracle JDK. Should I do it? If yes, why? If not, then how do I change the JDK to Oracle?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set the JDK for Android Studio?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/467870/how-to-set-the-jdk-for-android-studio)

Answer (score 3):

## Why choose Oracle Java?

Oracle Java is what most Java projects use. They test their products using it. They don't usually test their products on OpenJDK.

This means that bugs get fixed when they show up on Oracle Java. Bugs don't usually get fixed when they show up only on OpenJDK.

If you want a less buggy experience in general, Oracle Java is a better option.

## Installing Oracle Java the nice way

Ubuntu's APT package manager makes it easy to install software, uninstall software, and update software. If you want these benefits with Oracle Java, do the following (replace `java8` with the version you want; for example, to get Java 9, install `oracle-java9-installer` instead):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt update
sudo apt install oracle-java8-installer
```

## To switch between installed JDKs

1. List Java alternatives:

   ```
   update-java-alternatives -l
   ```
2. Find the line with the Java you want.
3. Remember the first part of the line. For example, Oracle Java 8's line  **might** look like this on your system:

   ```
   java-8-oracle                  1082       /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
   ```

   The first part of the line there is `java-8-oracle`.
4. Set the first part of the line you want as the Java alternative (replace `java-8-oracle` with the Java you want):

   ```
   sudo update-java-alternatives -s java-8-oracle
   ```

Comment: how to change the jdk from open jdk to oracle jdk in android studio?

Comment: Try this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/663557/147763

Answer (score 0):

Oracle Java is the JDK officially supported by android studio, and you can change your jdk setting using

```
update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_20/bin/java" 1    
update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_20/bin/javac" 1
```

Change in command line according to the version downloaded and path.

Comment: Actually I am sking shoiuld I change from Open JDK to Oracle JDK

Comment: `update-java-alternatives` is the proper way to switch Java over. Your instructions miss out on things like `javap` and other Java executables as well as the web browser plugin.