# How can I select a certain version of Java?

Tags: command-line, java

I can't install Java 7. I selected it as advised, but nothing changes when I type `java -version`.

when I type `sudo update-alternatives --config java` I get:

```
There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java 1075        auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java 1074        manual mode
```

when I type `1` and then <kbd>enter</kbd> and then run `java -version` I find that my choice has not been effective.

[image: java]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing JDK from Open JDK to Oracle JDK](http://askubuntu.com/questions/751300/changing-jdk-from-open-jdk-to-oracle-jdk)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this command:

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

You'll get a result similar to:

```
There are 3 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java          1093      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1081      manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java          1093      manual mode
  3            /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/bin/java       1091      manual mode
```

Answer the prompt for the version you wish to run.

---

You can remove the versions that don't work then ensure a good install of the one you want to use:

Look at: [Problem changing Java version using alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2716386/1204365)

  The user in the accepted answer in the link resolved this problem by removing
  **ALL**
  the installed java versions and installing the ones he wanted to use.  After this the `sudo update-alternatives --config java` command worked.

**After you have removed the problem versions, you can install the version you want to run with:**

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo install oracle-jdk7-installer
```

Comment: I already tried that I chose for example 1 then installs but when I type java -version nothing chnage

Comment: @lyly Can you update your question with the text that you have in your image.  I can't make out the exact response.  If it were in text I could use Google's translator to better decipher the error response.

Comment: I followed the same guy you told me to install java 8 but still the old version remained

Comment: @lyly Try first selecting 0 and 2 and see if it changes.  Make sure (which I understand that you're doing) that you use the elevated `sudo` prefix to your command.

Comment: I have already had my teacher has to prblm rrivé to change the version with a method that I forgot that she parcque chnage not and I do not remember how he blocked ss I do I have switched this version please help me james

Comment: @lyly Try apt-get remove to remove the unwanted versions.  During this might resolve also resolve the `update-alternatives` problem.

Comment: @james james please I Tappe sudo apt-get remove java6 me or what I want parcque java8 installed and before I have java 6

Comment: @james you are here

Comment: @lyly I'm trying to move this extended comment session to chat.  Give me a moment to research.

Comment: @lyly In the meantime you can use `apt-cache search` to find the package names of the other java versions and use `sudo apt-get remove` them by name.

Comment: @lyly One type search to remove the version 6, try: `apt-cache search java.*6.*oracle`.  Then remove the packages from the search result.

Comment: james sorry I insisted I just tried what you say but my m displays no command

Comment: `update-java-alternatives` should be used so that associated programs like `javap` are updated as well.

Comment: @lyly Can you type in the exact command you typed that gave you the no command error?

Comment: thanx james youra are my best I succeeded

Comment: @lyly You're welcome.  Consider placing a check mark with the answer since this helped.

Comment: you're the one who helped me merci james

Comment: @lyly Glad it worked.

Comment: @james jet same problem Java 6 has been removed I have Tappe sudo update-alternatives --config java
I board selected 1 to 8 java then when I type java -version
No such file or dirctory

Comment: @lyly What is the output of the `sudo update-alternatives --config java`.  Add the text to your question.

Comment: sudo update-java-alternatives -l

Comment: java-7-oracle  1074 /user/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle

Comment: java-8-oracle 1075 /user/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle

Comment: @lyly What is the full output you get when you type in `sudo update-alternatives --config java`  Paste the full output to a message.

Comment: a typed sudo update-java-alternatives -s java-7-oracle

Comment: @lyly I don't know if you're saying the alternative method is working.  If you are still having problems, I'll need to see the output of the command I gave you.  Are you still having problems?

Comment: sorry when I type sudo update-alternatives --config java
there are two choices for the alternative java (which provides / user / bin / java)
selction the way state priority
0 / user / lib / jvm / java-8-oracle / jre / bin / java 1075 automatic
/ User / lib / jvm / java-7-oracle / jre / bin / java 1074 manual
/ User / lib / jvm / java-8-oracle / jre / bin / java 10755 manual

Comment: @lyly Ok.  So the next step is to install the version that you want to run.  I'll add the command for the installation to my answer.  Give me a couple minutes to format it easy to read.

Comment: @lyly Which version of Ubuntu are you running?  16.04?

Comment: @james no 14.04

Comment: @lyly Look at the last 4 lines of my answer.

Comment: @james I do not see anything

Comment: @james you are her

Comment: @lyly Are you looking at the answer just below your question?  You'll see my avatar which is a yellow and read box.

Comment: @jmaes I installed java java 8 and 7 my problem I can not get the sélctionné you understand me

Comment: @lyly The same way I edited my answer.  Will you edit your question?  Run this command:  `sudo update-alternatives --config java`  Copy and paste what you get in the terminal screen to your question.  So that I can see the exact output.  This is similar to the original picture that you posted.  Paste it to your question.

Comment: when I type sudo update-alternatives --config java there are two choices for the alternative java (which provides / user / bin / java) selction the way state priority 0 / user / lib / jvm / java-8-oracle / jre / bin / java 1075 automatic / User / lib / jvm / java-7-oracle / jre / bin / java 1074 manual / User / lib / jvm / java-8-oracle / jre / bin / java 10755 manual

Comment: when I type sudo update-alternatives --config java there are two choices for the alternative java (which provides / user / bin / java) selction the way state priority 0 / user / lib / jvm / java-8-oracle / jre / bin / java 1075 automatic / User / lib / jvm / java-7-oracle / jre / bin / java 1074 manual / User / lib / jvm / java-8-oracle / jre / bin / java 10755 manual

Comment: I can't make out the text in the comment.  This what you just pasted here, click on `edit` to where you typed your original question.  Paste it there.  It'll make it easy for me to read and see what teh problem is.  I believe it'll take just minutes after I can see this text in your question.

Comment: @lyly If you can't copy and paste the text.  Paste another image and I'll see what is happening from there.

Comment: @lyly I will be able to see from the text which java is selected, or I will be able to understand what error is happening if I can see the exact text that comes on your screen when you type in the command.

Comment: @james I modified you can see the

Comment: @lyly What you put there is something that you typed.  Look at what is in my answer how the output looks.  Did you use the `copy` and `paste` command so that you could have the output exactly the way it was on your screen?  What I'm looking at won't work.

Comment: @lyly Also, I believe there is a problem with your Java installation.  I was hoping to look at the exact output to help identify the problem.  But if you would remove versions 7 and 8, then use the command I gave you in the answer (as well as in the link I provided), I'm sure the problem would be resolved.  I would hope to see the exact output so that I can see where the `*` is on the your screen.

Comment: @james thanx for helping me I abandon I unable

Comment: @james I have posted another question with the same problem you may please see

Comment: @I would recommend that you not post a duplicate question with the same problem.  That is strictly against the rules.  There already are two answers to your question here.  You have to be patient and sometimes wait a day or so for the best answer.

Comment: @JAMES VOUS AVEZ VU MA PUBLICATION

Comment: @lyly Yes.  I didn't down-vote your question, but I knew it would be down-voted because as I mentioned, duplicating questions is strictly against the rules.  I adding formatting to my answer that might make it easier for you to follow.  I added clarification to make it ease for others having a similar problem.  I believe there was something wrong with your original installation.

Comment: @james hello you are here 
I found no answer for my publication please help me

Comment: @lyly Did you remove all the java versions as indicated in the answer?

Comment: @james not because I know which version is supported scala I want to try java7 with scala 2.11.6 if it works I will not use java 8 below for that I want kept the two versions

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44789/discussion-on-answer-by-l-d-james-how-can-i-select-a-certain-version-of-java).

Comment: @lyly Look at my response at: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44789/discussion-on-answer-by-l-d-james-how-can-i-select-a-certain-version-of-java

Comment: @L.D.James I posted a question you can view please

Answer (score 0):

## To switch between installed JDKs

1. List Java alternatives:

   ```
   update-java-alternatives -l
   ```
2. Find the line with the Java you want.
3. Remember the first part of the line. For example, Oracle Java 8's line  **might** look like this on your system:

   ```
   java-8-oracle                  1082       /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
   ```

   The first part of the line there is `java-8-oracle`.
4. Set the first part of the line you want as the Java alternative (replace `java-8-oracle` with the Java you want):

   ```
   sudo update-java-alternatives -s java-8-oracle
   ```

Comment: when I type sudo update-java-alternatives -s java-7-oracle
nothing changes I should do please