# Where is "Project Structure" in Android Studio 4.1

Tags: android-studio

I have multiple versions of Java installed, and I wanted to set which one it used for my Flutter project in Android Studio.  All the documentation I can find says to go to File > Project Structure, but I can't find it.
[image: My Android Studio file menu]

For example, here are some of the places that refer to the Project Structure menu item:

- [How to set the JDK for Android Studio?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/467870/how-to-set-the-jdk-for-android-studio)
- https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config#jdk

Has this moved to somewhere else?  Am I missing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm just through with the same issue. Probably this should solve your problem too.

Go to **Tools** > **Flutter** > **Open for Editing in Android Studio**

You will be asked to open the Project in the same window or new window. Choose any. Another window will open. There in the **File** menu, you will find **Project Structure**.

After you are done with your work you can move back to your original project by going to **File** > **Open Recent**

Answer (score 0):

I've just experience the same. In my case gradle sync failed because it didn't find the version of NDK it wanted to (I don't know where that version is specified), and I couldn't select the latest version that I do have installed because there was no "Project structure" in the menu. So, I specified the correct NDK version in build.gradle:

```
android {
    ndkVersion '21.3.6528147'
}
```

After this sync succeeded and "Project structure" appeared in the menu. And the NDK version is no longer selectable there (but you still can select the Gradle version as before). It seems that this way of selecting the NDK (via local.properties) is deprecated.

Comment: I'm not sure that I am using the NDK in my project.  I did try to add that section, and it didn't seem to make a difference.  I'm not sure if it didn't sync or what.